What should I do if I am not able to reproduce the coauthors’ results?
We are doing computational biology research using ML. My coauthor who is a Phd student initially proposed a new idea that he said worked better than the baseline. However, after trying to replicate the result, I could not reproduce it. I have asked him repeatedly, but he seemed trying to avoid telling me how to reproduce the result and asked me to do something else. It seems to me that he is also not able to reproduce his own result and his idea does not even beat the baseline. Even when knowing that he could not reproduce his own result and his result did not make sense, he spent another 5 months on a mini project exploring this direction and he also kept pushing to submit the papers. Furthermore, the datasets that were used to train the models were not consistent, there is a new version of the dataset that is “easier” (due to random seed, and slightly different codes), but he keeps saying that the two datasets are the same and used interchangeably in the paper. I investigated, and the data was not the same and he was lying even to my PI.
I have worked for 2 - 3 years on this paper as a second or third author, but I am worried about working with this coauthor because I don’t trust what he’s doing. If I told my PI, the PhD would not be happy and may retaliate with more dishonesty. Despite the dishonesty, the PhD is very hardworking, so the PI may not believe me as well. What should I do? Should I take my name off the paper? or it is just a small matter and not a big misconduct? I have been working on this for 3 years, so I have a lot of sunk cost. This is my first paper and I want to use it to apply for graduate school. I also have an opportunity to keep doing the project and get a cofirst which will help my career and graduate school applications. Should I continue working with him? Or should I start over on a new project? I honestly have trust issues with whatever he’s doing, I don't know what’s true and not true anymore. I don’t like the fact that these kinds of people are more successful and have more papers than the average PhD..

To be clear: You're currently an undergraduate student? A year or so from graduating? What part of the world?

I’m a post bachelor RA with 5 years of experience in south east Asia. I worked on this project one year before the PhD came in.

"post bachelor RA" isn't understood everywhere. Are you enrolled in a degree program? If so, is it a masters or is it a doctorate?

@Buffy No, I am a full time RA after I get my bachelors degree. What do you think of this problem Buffy? Should I try to work with him or should I move on to the other project?

Before tossing accusations, talk to the PI or your major professor about your concerns.

@Part-timeEngineer have talked to my PI and eventually, my PI knows that the PhD's result is not reproducible. The PhD couldn't reproduce his own result.

@ivicts OMG, so it seems like a research misconduct is going on, if your PI really knows this. One thing I can assure you is that right now because of the development of AI, research misconduct WILL be detected, just a matter of time! I'd stay away from this research group and stop working with them. If I were you, I wouldn't even want my name on this paper. You are just an undergrad, you still have a long way to go. This is just my thought.

I think you're getting fine advice, so I won't answer further -- but I would like to know if your school is one of those that uses a real honor code.  In a place like that, your silence about a suspicion of dishonesty might be considered an honor code violation, which may certainly impact decisions you might make.

@Part-timeEngineer from what the OP has said, they are not an undergrad — they have a Bachelor’s degree and are now employed full-time with this research group as a research assistant. So this is more complex — the only way to stay away from the research group is to resign. Certainly, though, don’t put your name on this paper.

@Part-timeEngineer My coauthor who is a Phd student initially proposed a new idea that he said worked better than the baseline. This more complicated idea actually doesn't work better than the baseline. The PhD cannot reproduce the result that his idea actually beat the baseline, so he just adds a lot of things to the model that are just simply noise. This idea doesn't even make sense biologically, and my colleagues have pointed that out, but he's so stubborn and keep pushing for submission even when he himself couldn't replicate his idea. The PI was initially reluctant to submit the paper.

@Significance In the end, the reviewers are also suspicious about this idea, the paper gets rejected, and the idea that was not reproducible was removed, so the model goes back to my original model, but I went down from the second author to third author just because the PhD adds a lot of noise to the model that got us rejected. This paper is 3 years of work, if I take my name off, I have nothing after 3 years of work.. that's my concern. It's not like I have so many papers that I have the privilege to take my name off.

@ivicts Sir, I don't know which university you are working at and and which country you are living in. But if you have reported your suspicions about research misconduct to your PI and your PI just let it go without any action, then this is not right at all. Check website like PubPeer; research misconduct is exposed every day and every moment. So, for your own reputation, stay away from toxic research groups. Publishing a paper but based on the manipulated results, it is absolutely not worth.

@ScottSeidman I feel that I am too outspoken, critical & belligerent on this (among other things) and I got excluded, the PhD was reluctant sharing things to me now and I went from second author to third author. If I just went along and wait until the paper got rejected by the reviewers and telling them to go back to the right track, I might have a cofirst author by now.

@Part-timeEngineer that is what I disagree about with my PI. My PI was actually mad at this and mention to the PhD before his presentation to the group that he can't reproduce his own result and his idea doesn't beat the simple baseline. However, he still lets the PhD submits it. I feel that the PhD pushed my PI too hard on this because my PI is usually perfectionist, but as a PI he has power to do the right thing. Do you think adding a lot of stuff that doesn't work and not reproducible considered manipulated result? The new version of the paper doesn't have this idea though after rejection.

I am still confused whether I should try to work with the PhD. People say we should try to work with someone we don't like & we disagree with, how about someone we don't trust? Should I try to professionally work with him? or should I just stay away from him?

@ivicts Sir, I am not familiar with your field, and it is hard for me to say now.

Given what you say, the minimum is to take your concerns, along with the evidence, to the PI. If you are an undergraduate you will need to defer to their judgement.
As for leaving (or staying with) the project, that is a much riskier situation. As the "junior" partner and an undergrad, few would blame you, no matter what you do, but arranging a new project with a new PI takes time.
But if the doctoral student is lying about the research, it is a big deal. Make sure of your facts before you do anything.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I worry we've been understating things if you're concerned that not working with this charlatan is "too purist", as you said in the comments. If they're fabricating results, they're a terrible person and a disgrace to scientists everywhere. If you were to go along with it, you'd be a terrible person and a disgrace to scientists everywhere. I can't say whether you should definitely try to report them to the PI, the department head, and the editor of the journal (my inclination is to say go for the throat, but I understand if you don't have the clout to do that yet), but under absolutely no circumstances should you participate in this fraud.
The fact that you've already talked to the PI and the bad guy is apparently still trying to convince them to publish this suggests that the PI might be on your side here. Talk to them about it, and don't understate your concerns. Flat out say, "This paper claims that these experiments were done on the same dataset, and that's a lie."
Accusations of fraud are serious, and I could understand being reticent to make a public accusation without having all your evidence ready to go, but if you're just having a private conversation with your PI, don't worry about being diplomatic. Just speak openly and honestly about exactly what you've observed. They have the experience to know how bad this type of fraud is and what to do about it. You have the evidence that that's what's happening here. Provide every bit of information you have available so they can make the right call.
Two more things:

but if I’m able to find a way to work with him, I can get a cofirst author which will help me in my career, that’s the dilemma.

That's extremely dangerous thinking. Fraud usually helps someone's career; that's why people do it. Doing things that benefit you at the expense of others is almost the definition of evil. And this is at the expense of others. A fraudulent paper wastes the time of every honest scientist who tries to build on the work. In some fields (e.g., medicine, civil engineering), fraudulent research can kill people. There is never any excuse to fabricate data.

"I’m still wondering on how to go about this in a way that doesn’t alienate the Phd?"

When Houdini exposed the people running seances as frauds, he didn't make any friends among them. But why would he want to? They were scammers who took advantage of the naivete of others for their own selfish gains. Which of the two are better remembered by history? If you expose a fraud (and especially if you lose a paper because of it, although more likely, you'd just correct the paper so it honestly reports the real results), you will be viewed as a scientist who acts with honor and integrity by anyone whose opinion matters.

Would just being a third author mean "participating in this fraud"? I have talked to the PI after the paper submissions that some of the results are not reproducible. The PI did not say anything and called the PhD into the office to test the model and see which one really worked and not, but the paper got submitted anyway. After the revision, the PI said that everything is reproducible now. However, I could not check myself because I was excluded from the project since the PhD was not happy with me double-checking his work and knowing more than I should.

@ivicts If you're a coauthor, you're responsible for anything in the paper. If you know it's bogus and still attach your name to it, you're part of it.  If the PI said everything's reproducible now, maybe things got fixed? I don't know. You need to talk to the PI about your concerns and see if they've been addressed or not, I think.

since I am excluded, I am unable to take over. Well, the funny thing was the PhD went on on a mini project building on his result that he could not even reproduce himself, and then it was just a failure after 5 months. The problem is I alienated the PhD, was excluded from the project, and could not take over. If I just went along and waited until the reviewers rejected the papers, I could take over and ensure the whole thing is consistent and reproducible. So, I feel that sometimes if I just stay away from the paper, it does not help the cause..

I don't know.. but I need something in my CV after three years of work.. if I have no papers, it can end my career as well. Things got fixed after the rejections, but I am not in the project anymore to double check things. @Ray

Yeah, I don't know. I'm afraid I've given all the advice I can without actually seeing the data and the paper and talking the PI and...etc. If you're on good terms with the PI, they're the one you really need to have a conversation with until you're both satisfied that the paper is legit. (And if it's submitted but not accepted yet, there'll still be time for edits). For the conversation, maybe phrase it as you wanting to understand why the paper is legitimate instead of starting off by making accusations? That might help it go smoother (interpersonal stuff isn't exactly my forte, though).

I'm excluded from the project and not doing it anymore now.. I was given a project where I could be a co-first author partly because probably the PI felt bad that I was right all along but he excluded me, so I am focusing on that instead of a third author work. The sad thing is people who engage in this kind of fraud are more successful and get a co-first instead... where I'm a third author after exclusion

I know interpersonal stuff is not your forte lol because you sound exactly like me. Straight to the point, "purist" morally, and not diplomatic. Sometimes these things cannot be solved straight to the point the way we want it to be. Because alienating someone even if you are right will not help to advance the cause, there is a tradeoff somewhere..

Yeah. Well, if nothing else, at least remember this when you're at a point in your career where you do have the power to fight the good fight effectively.

Also, I read a lot of authorship dispute questions and I feel that the consensus is that maintaining professional relationships sometimes is more important than authorship. How about integrity vs relationship? If I spoke out about integrity, I would alienate someone one way or the other. Which one is more important integrity or professional relationships?

@ivicts I would say integrity. If it's an authorship dispute like "I should probably be first author but I'm willing to take second author if it'll keep the professional relationships running smooth", that's fine.  If it's an issue of honesty, though: integrity. If the results we report aren't true, then why are we even scientists?

so should I find a way to work with him despite the disagreement or should I just stay away from him completely and do another project with other people? he's very hardworking and motivated though..

Motivated to do good science or motivated to advance his career? Do you want to face a similar situation again? If there are honest people to work with, work with them.

For me, personally, I would stay away from them. But, people say that we should work with people with whom we disagree... so you mean this is not a question of disagreement but about ethics. For disagreement, we can still work it out, but for ethics, it's better to stay away from them?

and I don't even need to maintain a good relationship with them?

If the datasets are meaningfully different, they know this fact, and they reported otherwise, they are unethical and should be avoided (and reported, in a perfect world, but I'll leave that decision to you). If the datasets are different but they don't believe this to be the case, their competence is questionable, but we all make honest mistakes from time to time, so it's not as bad. If you point the honest mistake out and they hold fast to their view, then the question is whether you've adequately proven that the datasets are different. If so, the honest mistake becomes dishonest.

long story short, the PhD knew that the datasets were different but never told us (including the PI), I have confronted him about this. The PI actually thought I was the one who made things up because of this. When I said the datasets were different, I needed to make 20 PPT slides to show that the same models applied on different datasets yield different results because he denied it. After presenting, he's still pushing to submit the paper without retraining the model. So, it clears that he doesn't do thing in a good faith.

How can I cope that someone who has committed fraud can easily get papers out? They will be more successful and have more papers in high-impact journals as a cofirst than mine. I am here doing good science and can only get a third author...

@ivicts If crime didn't pay, people wouldn't do it. As for how to cope with it, I see two main options: you can recognize that doing good research is more important than getting first author and be satisfied with that. Low risk, low reward. Or you can try to bring down the frauds. I'm not sure what sort of whistleblowing procedures (and whistleblower protection) exist where you are, or what the risks are, but you might see if your institution has an office that handles that. If so, they can probably give way better advice than I can on what to do next.

@ivicts  If not, maybe inform the editor of the journal? Some countries and fields also have organizations like the Office of Research Integrity that can help.
